# Remove recursively "_v1" from files in multipe sub folders

Tags: powershell

I have multiple files stored in folders and subfolders. Almost all of them contain _v1 at the end of the BaseName. I tried the following but I'm getting an error.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse * -Filter "/(_v1)/" |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '/(_v1)/','' } -WhatIf
```

Error:

> Get-ChildItem : Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\test\ " -recurse  -Filter "*_V1*" | % { Rename-Item $_ -NewName $($_.Name -replace "_V1","" ) }
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell isn't Perl. Forward slashes don't indicate a regular expression, they're just literal forward slashes, so neither your filter expression nor your search string will match the intended files. Also, the parentheses (i.e. the capturing group) serve no purpose, so you should remove them.

Use a wildcard pattern as the filter string for `Get-ChildItem` and apply the regular expression replacement to the basename to avoid unintentional replacements of `_v1` elsewhere in the file names.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*_v1.*' -Recurse |
    Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.BaseName -replace '_v1$') + $_.Extension }
```

If you're running at least PowerShell v3 you can add the parameter `-File` to `Get-ChildItem` so that it won't return directories.